# Method() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, selenium

Good Morning, I've been having an issue with one of our scripts, this was made by one of my colleagues.

The main point was to have a wrapper Driver that extends some of the usability of python, in it we have some methods to make mousehover actions easier, and some other functionalities, in it, we have something like

```
Class SuperDriver: 
    def __init__(self, driver: object) -> object:
        self._driver = driver

    def wait_and_get(self, mode, key):
        return WebDriverWait(self._driver, self.WAIT_TIMEOUT).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((mode, key)))

    def wait_and_move_to(self, mode, id):
        elem = self.wait_and_get(self._driver, mode, id)
        ActionChains(self._driver).move_to_element(elem).perform()
```

When I try to use it in another script I go with

```
from utils.super_driver.SuperDriver import SuperDriver

Class class1:
      def class1_test(self):

          sd1 = Superdriver(driver)

          sd1.wait_and_move_to(driver, By.XPATH, xpath)
```

And then it says

> TypeError: wait_and_move_to() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

I've tried with

```
   sd1.wait_and_move_to(By.XPATH, xpath)
```

This time said

> TypeError: wait_and_get() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

```
   sd1.wait_and_move_to(xpath)
```

This resulted in

> TypeError: wait_and_move_to() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

```
   sd1.wait_and_move_to(self, By.XPATH, xpath)
```

And this one resulted in

> TypeError: wait_and_move_to() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Anything that came out of my mind but, nothing worked, so, some help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: @Andersson what about trying to think instead of programming by accident ?

Comment: `wait_and_move_to()` takes an implicit `self` and  2 args, so your first example is correct. However, your call `self.wait_and_get(self._driver, mode, id)` in `wait_and_move_to()` has an extra parameter and just needs `self.wait_and_get(mode, id)`.

Comment: "I've tried with (...) anything that came out of my mind" : this is not how you're going to learn. Trying to understant the error message and the code (and the language you're using) is a better strategy... Also, the second call example (`sd1.wait_and_move_to(By.XPATH, xpath)`) can NOT result in the error message you posted, and "Nothing worked"  is the most useless description of a problem.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers there's a call in `wait_and_move_to()` that has too many params so does raise the same Exception but from a different line.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I've edited the question with the rest of the errors, I've been trying because I'm newbie with Python, and It's being a bit difficult to understand some stuff

Comment: @AChampion I tried to change the [link](self.wait_and_get(mode, id)) line but keep saying the same error

Comment: @DavidMarínSánchez from which line?

Answer (score 6):

The correct invocation is:

```
sd1.wait_and_move_to(By.XPATH, xpath)
```

The object `sd1` is implicitly passed as the first argument and becomes `self` in the method `def wait_and_move_to(self, mode, id):`

However, if you were to look at the line number of the exception you would see the `TypeError` is being thrown from here:

```
def wait_and_move_to(self, mode, id):
    elem = self.wait_and_get(self._driver, mode, id)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The correct call is:

```
def wait_and_move_to(self, mode, id):
    elem = self.wait_and_get(mode, id)
    ...
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please spend some time to understand what is happening, guessing at solutions isn't going to be productive long term.